# PyGTK Window always on top of all 'always on top` windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, user-interface, pygtk

I created a PyGTK application which needs to be always on top. The transparent window redirects mouse clicks to the window below and therefore gets out of focus once you click into an underlaying window. This is the intended behaviour. In fact it should just show a little image that's always above everything.

This works well unless you use something like the libreoffice fullscreen presentation. The presentation window is marked as `always on top` as well and hence my window goes into the background. Even if I take it to front using `Alt+Tab` and then click onto the underlaying libreoffice slide (which is neccessary) my window goes into the background again.

This is a really specific question and the solution should work on both Linux and Windows. I have no idea what I should do. I just found many questions on how to have a windows `always` on top but none of them covering my problem.

**Long story short:** How can I put my window always on top of every window that is always on top as well?

Answer (score 6):

**Simple Answer:** You can use 'Always on Top' in windows with by using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) scripts.

***Follow these steps*:**

- Install [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)
- Create a new AHK scripts following the images
- Add this code `^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A`
- Next, double-click your script to run it. You’ll know it’s running
  because a green **“H”** logo appears in your system tray to let you know
  it’s running as a background process.
- Now press **Ctrl+Space** to set any currently active window to be always
  on top. Press **Ctrl+Space** again set the window to no longer be always
  on top.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. However it's really important that I can compile the program into a single .exe (since I want to distribute it) and that there is an alternative which could be used on linux. Anyway thank you for your help!